# Self-expanding Widget, on mouse over

Tags: qt

I want to implement a widget (with some edit boxes and sliders) that would open beneath or next to a button ("Opener") when I hover it. The key is it's a temporary widget - as soon as it loses focus, I want it gone. Also, I want it to pop up right next to the Opener, ideally pointing an arrow to Opener.

So, it's basically a tooltip. But it needs to be a widget with buttons and sliders and stuff like that. Is there a clever way to implement it without making a custom widget and writing handlers for all the mouse and focus events and recomputing its ideal position every time I open it or the Opener moves?

Answer (score 3):

```
class OpenerButton : public QPushButton
{
public:
    OpenerButton(QWidget * parent = 0);
protected:
    void enterEvent(QEvent *e);
    void leaveEvent(QEvent *e);
};

OpenerButton::OpenerButton(QWidget * parent)
      : QPushButton(parent)
{
   //Do necessary initializations For ex:set a menu for opener button 
}

void OpenerButton::leaveEvent(QEvent * e)
{
          //hide the popup_menu
}

void OpenerButton::enterEvent(QEvent * e)
{
    //Show the menu
    //You can use animation for ex:
     Popup_menu=new Popup_Dialog(this);//Popup_Dialog is a dialog containing all your widgets
     QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation(Popup_menu,"geometry");
     animation->setDuration(500);
     animation->setDirection(QAbstractAnimation::Forward);
     QRect startRect(Rect_Relative_to_Opener_Button);
     QRect endRect(Shifted_Rect_Relative_to_Opener_Button);
     animation->setStartValue(startRect);
     animation->setEndValue(endRect);
     animation->start();

}
```

`Enterevent` is called when the mouse cursor enters the widget. Similarly `leaveevent` when mouse cursor leaves the widget.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the property animation feature - I didn't know about it!
Unfortunately, this doesn't really solve it. Parenting the Popup_Dialog to the button clips the dialog. I think you meant leave/enter to be the opposite? enterEvent can open the dialog, but if I get the leaveEvent() to close it, then the user never has a chance to move the mouse outside the Opener button and into the popup dialog widget. If the dialog focusOutEvent() hides it, then focusing in dialog controls causes it to hide itself.

And that's even before any tooltip-like behavior... Maybe it's unsolveable.

Comment: Ok then do nothing in leaveEvent.You can do this task without parenting to button too. Do the same enterevent leaveevent logic by developing a custom dialog for popup menu and implementing its leaveevent and enterevent...:)